# Jquery cookie not detect no exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

When the given cookie does not exist, the result must be **null** or **undefined**, but in this case **favouritescook** doesn't exist but the script thinks it does.

The result must be "OK Detect" for null or undefined, but the result is "BAD no detect result". Why isn't this working?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
actcookies=jQuery.cookie("favouritescook");
function fav(id)
{
    if (actcookies=='undefined' || actcookies=='null')
    {
        alert("OK detect");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("BAD Not detect Result : "+actcookies);
    }
}
</script>

<div onclick="fav(1);">Test Now 1</div>
```

I have tried this in different browsers, with the same result. I don't understand this.

Comment: Your condition is wrong.

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote. Your grammar is a bit rough, but it's obvious you aren't a native English speaker. You shouldn't get a downvote for that. Your question is just fine.

Comment: which version of jscookie you are using?

Comment: jquery.cookie plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will not return `undefined` you need to change your controller as

```
if (typeof actcookies=='undefined' || !actcookies)
{
    alert("OK detect");
}
else
{
    alert("BAD Not detect Result : "+actcookies);
}
```

Comment: Actually, a value can be undefined. While how you did it is correct, you can also check it without using `typeof`. Also, using the `!` operator actually changes what he is doing a bit, as that'd also be true if it was `0` or `false`, not just null.

Comment: Yes the problem was put ('') for this i need put withour quotes and put only undefined or null as true or false , this was my mistake , regards

Answer (score 2):

The problem is it doesn't equal the string `'undefined'` or the string `'null'`, it matches the values `undefined` and `null`, without the quotes (`''`).

Ditch the quotes and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
    actcookies=jQuery.cookie("favouritescook");
function fav(id)
{
    if (actcookies==undefined || actcookies==null)
    {
        alert("OK detect");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("BAD Not detect Result : "+actcookies);
    }
}
```